# Event listener doesn't trigger setState in web3js

Tags: web3js, react

I have the following function that does something with a smart contract, and then should manipulate the dapp state when the event has been received. However, it doesn't set the state of the dapp, and I'm not sure I'm listening to the event correctly.

```
try {
  await contract.methods
    .post(this.state.param1, `${this.state.content}`)
    .send({
      from: `${account}`,
      value: web3.utils.toWei(value.toString()),
      gas: 400000,
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("3", "gwei")
    });
  await contract.events.Posted({ fromBlock: "latest" }, function(
    err,
    result
  ) {
    if (!err) {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        buttonText: "Post",
        content: ""
      }).bind(this);
    }
  });
} catch (error) {
  // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
  alert(
    `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`
  );
  console.error(error);
}
```

After the successful execution of the contract, nothing happens with the state of the dapp (the button text and the loading are not set to what is needed). What am I missing here?